# How to only output the calculations done in the code into a csv file python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

So I am working on a code where I take values from the csv file and multiply them with some numbers but when I save and export the results the values from the imported file are also copied to the new file along with the results. I just want the results in the output file.

```
df = pd.read_csv('DAQ4.csv')  
   
df['furnace_power'] = df['furnace_voltage']*df['furnace_current']*0.52         #calculating the furnace power
df['heat_pump_power'] = (df['pump_current']*230)*0.62   

with open('DAQsol.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    thewriter = csv.writer(f)
df.to_csv('DAQsol.csv')
```

This is not the full code but should be enough to understand. so basically I just want the heat pump power and the furnace power to appear in the output file not the whole pump current and voltage from the imported DAQ 4 file.

Comment: We’re going to need to see some code …

Comment: Take the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [ask].

Comment: I just edit the code in there hope that makes my question clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
df['furnace_power'] = df['furnace_voltage']*df['furnace_current']*0.52         #calculating the furnace power
df['heat_pump_power'] = (df['pump_current']*230)*0.62
```

These two lines just modify the dataframe that you loaded. This means that all the other columns still exist, but just aren't modified. By calling `df.to_csv('DAQsol.csv')` you are saving the whole dataframe, with the unwanted and unmodified columns.

One way to not export these columns to the output `.csv` file, is to drop them out. This can be achieved with the following code:

```py
df.drop(columns=['unwanted_column_1', 'unwanted_column_two'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you have an example reading and saving in a diferent file after some calculations:

```
from os import sep
import pandas as pd

#reading the csv file as dataframe
df= pd.read_csv('DAQ4.csv',delimiter=';',header=None)

df['furnace_power'] = df['furnace_power'].apply(lambda x: x*x*0.52)
df['heat_pump_power'] = df['furnace_power'].apply(lambda x: x*230*0.62)

#saving the dataframe as csv file
df.to_csv('out_file.csv', sep=';', index=False)
```

I hope it works for you.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work. when I add this [,delimiter=';',header=None] my code gives me error.

Comment: Your answer has the same issue as the overall question. You are saving the whole data frame including the unwanted columns. For a further explanation, check my  answer.

Answer (score 0):

Just make an empty dataframe and populate it with your new calculations:

```py
df = pd.read_csv('DAQ4.csv')
df2 = pd.DataFrame()

df2['furnace_power'] = df['furnace_voltage']*df['furnace_current']*0.52         #calculating the furnace power
df2['heat_pump_power'] = (df['pump_current']*230)*0.62   

df2.to_csv('DAQsol.csv')
```